# Can't find the right way to build my own framework target with my main app target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I decided to split my main project in two parts to reuse code, in a iOS widget.

So I created a new target file in my xcworkspace (cocoa touch framework).
Both targets have some pod dependencies in common and I can't figure the way right way to build.

[image: Xcode targets]

**First try:**

In podfile, I've specified needed pods for both targets, but when building, I've multiple errors

> Class Foo is implemented in both MyApp and MyFramework. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

**Second try:**

Then I tried put framework target inside main app target (like we do usually with a test target)

```
target 'MyApp' do
    main_pods
    app_pods

    target 'MyFramework' do
        inherit! :search_paths

        target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
            inherit! :search_paths
            testing_pods
        end
    end
end
```

But then the framework won't build as it didn't found dependencies
Example:

> No such module Firebase

**Note**:

To build my main target, I've to build the framework target first, otherwise it's doesn't find 'MyFramework' module. No way to build both when I build the main target ?

Comment: seems the issue is related to Firebase, it's a static library and it's not doing well as a dependency of a dynamic framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, I had static libraries framework dependencies and the iOS linker does not support static library dependencies for dynamic libraries.

CF issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7126

I've solved it via Podfile by a workaround posted in the above issue:

```
post_install do |installer|
    sharedLibrary = installer.aggregate_targets.find { |aggregate_target| aggregate_target.name == 'Pods-SampleFramework' }
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
        if aggregate_target.name == 'Pods-SampleApp'
            aggregate_target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
                sharedLibraryPodTargets = sharedLibrary.pod_targets
                aggregate_target.pod_targets.select { |pod_target| sharedLibraryPodTargets.include?(pod_target) }.each do |pod_target|
                    pod_target.specs.each do |spec|
                        frameworkPaths = unless spec.attributes_hash['ios'].nil? then spec.attributes_hash['ios']['vendored_frameworks'] else spec.attributes_hash['vendored_frameworks'] end || Set.new
                        frameworkNames = Array(frameworkPaths).map(&:to_s).map do |filename|
                            extension = File.extname filename
                            File.basename filename, extension
                        end
                        frameworkNames.each do |name|
                            puts "Removing #{name} from OTHER_LDFLAGS"
                            config_file.frameworks.delete(name)
                        end
                    end
                end
                xcconfig_path = aggregate_target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
                config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have an app where I created a framework in a separate project but the same workspace. I use pods to get all external libraries, and embed my own framework in app's targets by adding it to `Embedded Binaries` in Xcode. My Podfile looks like this:

```
workspace 'MyApp'

abstract_target 'BasePods' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
    pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 4.1'
    project '../MyAppProject/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'

    target 'MyApp'
    target 'MyAppDevelopment'
end

target 'MyAppCore' do
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
    pod 'PromiseKit', '~> 4.1'
    project '../MyAppProject/MyAppCore/MyAppCore.xcodeproj'

      target 'MyAppCoreTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

What happens here I create two separate pod targets - one for the app, another one for the framework. I split them because they reside in different directories.

Comment: I don't have an xcodeproj for my framework target, and when I create two pods target (cf: first try in my post), xcode said there is duplicate (class implemented in both target)